# Uncaught TypeError: layer.getLayerStatesArray is not a function

Tags: openlayers

I am working on modify function for an Openlayers project. I define a vector layer for modify objects. (line, polygon etc.) But then I take an error like below while adding vector layer to map object. Why am i getting this?

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: layer.getLayerStatesArray is not a function
at ol-debug.js:17395
at ol.Collection.forEach (ol-debug.js:8289)
at ol.layer.Group.getLayerStatesArray (ol-debug.js:17394)
at ol.Map.ol.PluggableMap.renderFrame_ (ol-debug.js:18670)
at ol.Map.<anonymous> (ol-debug.js:17624)
```

Source Code (core)

```
        init: function (Map) {
            var self = this;
            self.Map = Map;
            self.VectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
            self.Map.olMap.addLayer(self.VectorSource);
            self.initialized = true;
        },
```

Source Code (UI)

```
var geo = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(e, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' })[0];
Max.Map.Draw.VectorSource.addFeature(geo);
```

[Referenced example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must give "ol.layer.Vector" object to addLayer method. For example:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector()
});

self.Map.olMap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```